# List all files modified or created by certain application

Tags: windows, monitoring, log-files, files

Is there a free tool to list all files modified by certain application?

What I would like to see is that I can start "monitoring" and start my application (MS Word). After that I can stop "monitoring" and my monitoring application will list all files modified by MS Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process Monitor

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx